# Getting error: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Touch' to `bool'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I keep getting this error whenever I run this code :

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.Touch' to
>   bool'

What is the issue here? I am trying to move a `gameObject` up when a finger touches the screen.

```
private Rigidbody rb;

void Start() {

rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

 }

 void Update () {

     if(Input.GetTouch()) {


         transform.position += Vector3.up;
     }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does `Input.GetTouch` return?

> Returns object representing status of a specific touch.

What are you doing here?

```
if(Input.GetTouch())
```

Instead of using a boolean expression or a boolean variable, you use an object ! This can't be compiled. There, inside the if statement, you have to use a condition or a boolean variable.

> How can we identify if the user made any touch?

```
if(Input.touchCount > 0)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because this condition:

```
if(Input.GetTouch())
```

doesn't return a `boolean` type. It returns [`touch`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch.html). To check have you touch or not, you should use it like this:

```
void Update () 
{
   if(Input.touchCount > 0) {
     transform.position += Vector3.up;
   }
}
```

If you want to know more information about touch detecting - check please [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html) unity manual.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html) API, `public static Touch GetTouch(int index);` returns a `Touch`, not a `bool`.